# Show all tables from my database but one?

Tags: mysql

I want to show all the tables from my database but one .
Now i know that the obvious way to do it would be like the following :

```
<?php
   $query = "SHOW TABLES";
   $result= mysql_query($query ) or exit(mysql_error());
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
     if ($row[0] != 'THE UNWANTED TABLE NAME') {
       echo '<option value="'.$row[0].'">'.$row[0].'</option>';
   }
 }
?>
```

MY question :
Is there any way to do this only via query, something like this :

```
$query = "show tables where 'condition to exclude the unwanted table' "
```

?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SHOW TABLES 
 FROM mydatabase 
WHERE Tables_in_mydatabase != 'THE UNWANTED TABLE NAME';
```

[**See more about `SHOW TABLES;` syntax here.**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html)

Replace `mydatabase` with your database name.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html
You can use:

```
SHOW [FULL] TABLES [{FROM | IN} db_name] [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```